# YAML files to Google BigQuery. What should my architecture on Google Cloud Platform be?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

This question concerns what should be an appropriate architecture on Google Cloud Platform for my particular use case.

I have a bunch of `.yaml` files that I would like to run SQL queries on using Google Cloud Platform's products. The combined size of these files would not be more than 30MB and each file would be on average about 50KB. New files would also not be added very frequently - about 2-3 times a year.

I was thinking I could design an architecture where all these files are saved on Cloud Storage, I run a Dataflow pipeline/Cloud Functions to convert these `.yaml` files to `.json` and then import them into BigQuery to run SQL queries.

What seems to be an appropriate approach? Using Dataflow or Cloud Functions for pre-processing or something else entirely?

I am also comfortable with Python so would be looking for a solution that incorporates that. For example Dataflow has a Python SDK.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Comment: Does it have to be SQL, or can you do a simple text search in say Node or Python?

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery probably isn't the right tool for this. Also, using a VM is a bit of work and will be expensive too. You'll also need to maintain that VM.

Here's an approach using Cloud Functions. I'm going to assume you don't **have** to use SQL and can simply load the file(s) contents into memory and simply do basic string searching. The code is a little crude and cobbled together from other answers on SO, but it should be enough to get you going.

- Create a Cloud Function (example uses Node, but could be Python too) to listen to your bucket and set the memory to an appropriate size e.g 256MB. That's because we'll be reading the contents into memory. Also, bump up the max execution time from the default of 60s.

[image]

- Deploy it.

[image]

- Upload a YAML file to the GCS  bucket and it will trigger the Cloud Function to execute and then read the contents of the file into memory.

[image]

[image]

- Examine the logs of the function that executed and you can see it read the contents of the YAML file into memory.

[image]

Here's the code:

`index.js`:

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.searchYAML = function searchYAML(event) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const file = event.data;
        (storage
            .bucket(file.bucket)
            .file(file.name)
            .download()
            .then(function(data) {
                if (data)
                    return data.toString('utf-8');
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log("New file " + file.name);
                    console.log(data);
                    //Do some searching/logic with the file contents here
                    resolve(data);
                }
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                reject(e);
            })
        );
    });
};
```

`package.js`:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your proposed ideas are a good fit.

It will take longer to launch Cloud Dataflow than the actual processing time (10 minutes to launch, 1 second to process). You are trying to use a Mac truck to deliver a toothpick.

30 MB of YAML files is tiny. By the time you wrote a Dataflow python script, you will have already converted your YAML files into Json.

YAML converted to Json is not a good use of BigQuery. BigQuery is column based for structured data. Converting and flattening Json can be problematic. This is a task for a simple in-memory NoSQL query engine.

This is a very small task that will easily fit on the smallest Compute Engine VM instance running a Python script. App Engine would be another good choice.

Comment: As you say, BigQuery won't shine with 30MB of data for sure. On the other hand BigQuery is a great place to permanently store structured data, so if what OP needs is a place to store files permanently and safely, and to be able to query them at will - it will be better than any volatile VM approach.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - Cloud Storage is a better place. YAML does not flatten very well. YAML is not a good type of data (terrible data) for BigQuery. What you wind up with is a giant column of Json that you then download and search in memory. Just use Cloud Storage, load the files into memory (they are only 30 MB total) and query.

Comment: Dataflow is out then. What about Cloud Functions? And yes @FelipeHoffa is correct. BigQuery offers me a great place to store and query data.
What managed database can I use then? I do not want the hassle of setting up VMs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am not too aware of how files in Cloud Storage can be queried. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JashShah - For this case, the total size of the files is 30 MB. Store the files in Cloud Storage for long term safe storage. Download the files into your computer's memory from Cloud Storage and search / query in memory using Python or the language of the day.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Makes sense. If I insist on using BigQuery, how do I ingest `.yaml` files properly?

Comment: You don't ingest YAML files into BigQuery. That is the point I am trying to make. BigQuery is column based. Think of how you will flatten YAML into one item per column and not lose the nested structure. YAML is more like a tree with parents and children. Usually YAML / Json is stored in a single column with some part stored in another column for indexing. BigQuery is a great product, but not for this case AND not cost effective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185164/discussion-between-jash-shah-and-john-hanley).

Comment: If you have further questions, open a new question. Long comment threads are not a good mechanism on StackOverflow.